# Equivalent formulation of $T_1$ condition.

Tags: general-topology

I was asked to prove the following theorem:

> A topological space if $T_1$ if and only if the following holds:
>
> For any subset $A$ of $X$, $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if and only if every neighborhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $A$.

I know how to prove the $\rightarrow$ direction, but given the equivalence of limit point vs. number of points it intersects with $A$, I cannot think of how we can link this to the $T_1$ condition.

Comment: This is not true in general. Take $X$ a finite set with the discrete topology or more generally a space $X$ with an isolated point $x$.

Comment: This result is from a Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space , at the point where it talks about the equivalent formulation of $T_1$ condition.

Comment: @HeroKenzan A [limit point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point#Definition) can't be isolated ...

Comment: Suppose $x\ne y$. Are $x$ and $y$ limit points of the set $A=\{x,y\}$?

Comment: @bof It depends on which kind of topology you are using.

Comment: My previous question was intended to be a hint towards proving the equivalence you asked about.

Comment: Note that, if $A=\{x,y\}$, the point $x$ certainly does not satisfy the condition "every neighborhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $A$". Therefore, if the topology is such that "$x$ is a limit point of $A$ if and only if every neighborhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $A$," then we can conclude that $x$ is not a limit point of the set $\{x,y\}$. What does that tell you about the topology?

Comment: Why do you think it implies that the topology is discrete??? The equivalence implies that, given two points $x\ne y$, the point $x$ is not a limit point of the set $\{x,y\}$, which in turn implies that there is a neighborhood of $x$ which does not contain $y$, which is one common formulation of the T$_1$ separation axiom.

Comment: @bof Sorry! I misread your comment. Yes you are right. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that if $A\subseteq X$ and $x$ is a limit point of $A$ then every open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ contains infinitely points of $A$.

Recall that one of the many equivalent formulations of $X$ being $T_{1}$ is that all singletons in $X$ are closed. Then let $x\in X$ and consider the singleton set $\{x\}$. If $\{x\}$ is not closed then $\{x\}$ has some limit point $y\neq x$ in $X$. Then every open neighbourhood of $y$ contains infinitely points of $\{x\}$, but thats clearly impossible. Therefore $\{x\}$ is closed and hence $X$ is $T_{1}$.